# java.sql.SQLException:No value specifies for paramerter 1

Tags: java, mysql, xampp, sqlexception

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
         try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/CSMS2","root","");
            String sql = "Select * from student_status where semester=?";
            String sql1 = "Select count(*) from student_status";
            String sql2 = "Select * from stocks where sno=1";
            String sql3 = "Update stocks set RS=? ,BS=? ,GS=? ,Files=? ,EDS=? where sno =1";
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            PreparedStatement pst1 = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
            PreparedStatement pst2 = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
            PreparedStatement pst3 = con.prepareStatement(sql3);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            ResultSet rs1 = pst1.executeQuery();
            ResultSet rs2 = pst2.executeQuery();
            int sno=1,SRS=0,SBS=0,SGS=0,SFiles=0,SEDS=0;
           if(rs.next() && rs1.next()&& rs2.next())
           {
             int count= rs.getInt(1);
             while(sno <=count)
             {
                int x= rs.getInt("semester");
                if (x ==1)
                {
                   int RS = 5,BS=1,GS=1,Files=6,EDS=0;  
                   SRS= SRS+RS; SBS= SBS+BS; SGS= SGS+GS; SFiles= SFiles+Files; SEDS= SEDS+EDS;
                }
                if (x ==2)
                {
                   int RS = 5,BS=1,GS=1,Files=6,EDS=10;   
                   SRS= SRS+RS; SBS= SBS+BS; SGS= SGS+GS; SFiles= SFiles+Files; SEDS= SEDS+EDS;
                }
                if (x ==3)
                {
                   int RS = 5,BS=1,GS=1,Files=6,EDS=0;
                   SRS= SRS+RS; SBS= SBS+BS; SGS= SGS+GS; SFiles= SFiles+Files ;SEDS= SEDS+EDS;
                }
                if (x ==4)
                {
                   int RS = 6,BS=1,GS=1,Files=6,EDS=0;
                   SRS= SRS+RS; SBS= SBS+BS; SGS= SGS+GS; SFiles= SFiles+Files; SEDS= SEDS+EDS;
                }
                if (x ==5)
                {
                   int RS = 5,BS=1,GS=1,Files=6,EDS=0;
                   SRS= SRS+RS; SBS= SBS+BS; SGS= SGS+GS; SFiles= SFiles+Files; SEDS= SEDS+EDS;
                }
                if (x ==6)
                {
                   int RS = 6,BS=1,GS=1,Files=6,EDS=0; 
                   SRS= SRS+RS; SBS= SBS+BS; SGS= SGS+GS; SFiles= SFiles+Files; SEDS= SEDS+EDS;
                }
                if (x ==7)
                {
                   int RS = 5,BS=1,GS=1,Files=6,EDS=0; 
                   SRS= SRS+RS; SBS= SBS+BS; SGS= SGS+GS; SFiles= SFiles+Files; SEDS= SEDS+EDS;
                }
                if(x ==8)
                {
                   int RS = 4,BS=1,GS=1,Files=5,EDS=0;   
                   SRS= SRS+RS; SBS= SBS+BS; SGS= SGS+GS; SFiles= SFiles+Files; SEDS= SEDS+EDS;
                }
              sno++;
             }
                int RSDB= rs2.getInt("RS");
                int BSDB= rs2.getInt("BS");
                int GSDB= rs2.getInt("GS");
                int FilesDB= rs2.getInt("Files");
                int EDSDB= rs2.getInt("EDS");

                int RSUDB= RSDB-SRS;
                int BSUDB= BSDB-SBS;
                int GSUDB= GSDB-SGS;
                int FilesUDB= FilesDB-SFiles;
                int EDSUDB= EDSDB-SEDS;
               // pst3.setInt(1,0);
                pst3.setInt(1,RSUDB);
                pst3.setInt(2,BSUDB);
                pst3.setInt(3,GSUDB);
                pst3.setInt(4,FilesUDB);
                pst3.setInt(5,EDSUDB);

                pst3.executeUpdate();     

         }

          con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"invalid");
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you have a question that goes along with that code?

Comment: 1) Besides adding a question as suggested by @Stultuske, change `catch(Exception e){ JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"invalid");` to `catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"invalid");` to help narrow down which of the **four versions** of the `PreparedStatement` is failing. General tips: 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) 4) Don't add ..

Comment: .. irrelevant tags like Swing. It may be code in a Swing app., but this problem would still occur in a command line app. (or a servlet etc).